# Get part of string in PHP without explode

Tags: php

I have the following string

```
$s = "hellomyname";
$result = ...
```

How can I get the "my" out of this the fastest way possible?

Comment: Based on what rules? You could use `substr($s, 5, 2)`, or do you mean to `str_replace('my', '', $s)`?

Comment: Yes, but i need to do this without an exact position. The character before the my and the one after are always the same.

Comment: e.g. i need something to work on both hellomyname and sasaomynsdsad and iomynh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the position of ((my)) in your string with `strpos()` function and then fetch the word with `substr()`.

here is an **example**:

```
<?php
    $s1 = 'laldkfjamydnadjacv zdvzkv';
    $pos = strpos($s1, 'my');
    echo 'First Position---> ' . $pos;
    $my1 = substr($s1, $pos, 2);
    echo '<br /> this is result---> ' . $my1;

    //second test
    $s2 = 'hellomyname';
    $pos2 = strpos($s2, 'my');
    echo '<br />Second position---> ' . $pos2;
    $my2 = substr($s2, $pos2, 2);
    echo '<br />this is second result---> ' . $my2;
?>
```

and this is **result**:

```
First Position---> 8
this is result---> my
Second position---> 5
this is second result---> my
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`substr($s, 5, 2)`](https://www.php.net/substr).

Answer (score 1):

## Explode (Delimiter, text)

In your case can use:

```
$result = explode('my', 'hellomyname'); // array([0] => 'hello', [1] => 'name');
```

If you need get the last value you can put end():

```
$result = end(explode('my', 'hellomyname')); //name
```

**Reference**

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php

https://www.php.net/end